# Are there any official rules which govern the announcement of pairings for a FIDE rated tournament?

Tags: rules, fide, swiss-pairing

Are there any specific rules for the pairing announcement, like they have to be announced **"x" hours** before the start of the next round? Or does it completely depend upon the tournament organisers? If this is the case, don't you think the organisers can be "lazy" sometimes and the players have to pay the price for their mistakes?

I tried searching Google and the FIDE rule handbook but couldn't really find anything useful.

Comment: Your second question (about laziness and mistakes) is very vague. It needs some additional information to ensure the readers will understand what you are driving at.  That would however turn it into a second question, and that may perhaps be better asked and answered in a different thread, once you have accepted an answer in this.

Comment: The answer to that second question is "Yes". That being said, if you do this then in next years edition you may get fewer participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any specific rules for the pairing announcement, like they have to be announced "x" hours before the start of the next round?

Of course not. What you suggest is totally impractical. Let me give you some examples.

Next month I will be chief arbiter in a [FIDE rated blitz tournament](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_details.phtml?event=329506). There will be 9 rounds starting at 11am and finishing about 3pm. At the end of each round, once all the results have been entered into the system, the pairings will be done, printed and an announcement made for the players to check the pairings and find their board. Normally I will be able to start the next round within 3 or 4 minutes of the pairings being published. The idea of waiting "several hours" before starting the round makes no sense.

In a week's time the Four Nations Chess League, one of the main organisers of FIDE rated chess in England, is running a [5 round FIDE rated weekend congress](https://4ncl.co.uk/fide/information_30.htm). Here is the schedule of rounds:

> Playing Schedule:
> Round 1 Friday 19.00 - 23.00
> Round 2 Saturday 10.00 - **14.00**
> Round 3 Saturday **15.00** - 19.00
> Round 4 Sunday 10.00 - **14.00**
> Round 5 Sunday **15.00** - 19.00

As you see on Saturday and Sunday there is a one hour gap scheduled between the morning and afternoon rounds. That means the pairings will be published less than one hour before the next round. With a 30 second increment if one game runs on for over 100 moves then that is likely to be much less than half an hour.